# React native module that allows you to copy/select the text contained in a view

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, npm, module

Is there a module that allows you to select/copy the text contained in a view?

[image: a busy cat]
[image: a busy cat]

If not, is there a way to know the number of all "Text" type tags and to extract the text contained in them in each of them?

```
<View>
<Text>Text1</Text>
<Text>Text2</Text>
<Text>Text3</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<Text selectable={true}>Text</Text>
```

It allows you to select a text in the specific tag "Text", its operation may depend on the version of react-native and the type of device used.